# Erlang, Nested JSON objects

Tags: json, parsing, erlang

Hi after decoding the JSON with mochijson2 I have ended up with this (Sample result)

```
{struct,
[{<<"query">>,
  {struct,
      [{<<"count">>,4},
       {<<"created">>,<<"2013-11-08T18:33:07Z">>},
       {<<"lang">>,<<"en-US">>},
       {<<"results">>,
        {struct,
            [{<<"quote">>,
              [{struct,
                   [{<<"symbol">>,<<"YHOO">>},
                    {<<"Ask">>,<<"32.99">>},
                    {<<"AverageDailyVolu"...>>,<<"18383000">>},
                    {<<"Bid">>,<<"32.98">>},
                    {<<"AskRealt"...>>,<<"32.9"...>>},
                    {<<"BidR"...>>,<<...>>},
                    {<<...>>,...},
                    {...}|...]},
```

I'm now trying to get the information from the Variables "symbol", "Ask" etc.. but I can't figure out how to get their. I tried doing it using proplists and this is how far I got:

```
{struct, JsonData} = Struct,
{struct, Ask} = proplists:get_value(<<"Ask">>, JsonData),
Key = proplists:get_value(<<"Ask">>, Ask),
Key.
```

Thanks for the help @legoscia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{ok, {{_, 200, _}, _Headers, Body}} = httpc:request(get, {"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json",[]},[],[]),
```

Then you'll have the response in the `Body` variable, and that's what you need to pass to mochijson.